# Proper method to use for receiving large chunk of files from an endpoint

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm currently shuffling between URLSession Download Task and Alamofire to stream data from an endpoint. I keep getting and error when I perform a regular GET request. To be precise this is the error:

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted tried to allocate 98570240 bytes`

I've used this code:

```
AF.streamRequest(urlString).responseStream { stream in
        
        print(stream)
        
    }
```

But got this error:

````
Stream<Data, Never>(event: Alamofire.DataStreamRequest.Event<Foundation.Data, Swift.Never>.complete(Alamofire.DataStreamRequest.Completion(request: Optional(https://api.axocheck.com/api/v1/schedule/eyJpdiI6ImxxWWgxU1BEY2NvTmJvNUxpa0VVbnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQTdHeVV0QjdLb0cwK0krK3BkVzB5dz09IiwibWFjIjoiZTNkNmY4MTFhNzdkNGEyNDM4YjE1NmE1M2VjOTUxM2M4MjJiYzYzMjMyMzcyNTE5NTJlMjY1NWY2MDVmOGEyMiJ9/download-report), response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x281524d80> { URL: https://api.axocheck.com/api/v1/schedule/eyJpdiI6ImxxWWgxU1BEY2NvTmJvNUxpa0VVbnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQTdHeVV0QjdLb0cwK0krK3BkVzB5dz09IiwibWFjIjoiZTNkNmY4MTFhNzdkNGEyNDM4YjE1NmE1M2VjOTUxM2M4MjJiYzYzMjMyMzcyNTE5NTJlMjY1NWY2MDVmOGEyMiJ9/download-report } { Status Code: 404, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "private, must-revalidate"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 13 Apr 2021 09:34:47 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "-1"
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    Server =     (
        "nginx/1.18.0"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "PHP/7.3.24"
    );
} })

) ```

And when I use the regular GET method I get that Memory error above. Please any form of help is appreciated. Thanks.
````

Comment: The second error seems to be a classic http 404, not sure how we can help with that.

Comment: Is there a proper way to stream data from an endpoint using Alamofire? I think that's my main issue. @JoakimDanielson